# I want to console.log a random array it works when I pass in a number but it doesn't when I directly hard code it in the console.log()

Tags: javascript, reactjs

When I do this, the code works.

```
console.log(characters.data.results[2])
```

I would obviously get the third object in the array. but this is static. I want it to be randomized so I did this.

```
console.log(Characters.data.results[Math.floor(Math.random() * 21)])
```

it didn't work, I keep getting this error

```
Main.jsx:6 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'results')
at Main (Main.jsx:6:1)
at renderWithHooks (react-dom.development.js:16175:1)
```

I even made the code cleaner by doing

```
const random = Math.floor(Math.random() * 21);
console.log(characters.data.results[random])
```

but I got the same error. What am I doing wrong? I am new to react.

Comment: Is characters.data undefined on the first render and change later?

Answer (score 0):

The value of `Characters.data` is undefined on first render and maybe changing afterwards.

To make sure `Characters.data` is not undefined before accessing `Characters.data.results`. You can use optional chaining (?.)

```js
console.log(Characters.data?.results[Math.floor(Math.random() * 21)])
```